# How to switch Visual Studio project from Windows to Linux container?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

How to switch Visual Studio 2019 **project file** from Windows to Linux container?

I got Error CTC1005 in Visual Studio 2019, project ASP.NET Core 3.0
*Your Docker server host is configured for 'Linux', however your project is configured for Windows.*

Desktop Docker running Linux containers.
The Docker file supports Linux container. Here it is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Comment: Look here: https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/aspnet-container/containerize.  BTW, the concept of "Visual Studio" on "Linux" comes as a bit of a shock ;)

Comment: Link appears dead FYI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your .csproj file and you will see that the docker OS is in there, just change `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>` to `Linux` ie.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    ...
   </PropertyGroup>

   ...
</Project>
```